# Custom edit post column - category not showing

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, post-editor

I added a custom column to a custom post type:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'custom_columns', 10);  
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns_thumb', 10, 2);  

function custom_columns($columns) {         
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'categories' => 'Categories', // not showing
        'thumb' => __('Thumb'),
        'date' => __( 'Date' )
    );
    return $columns;
}  

function custom_columns_thumb($column_name, $id){  
    if($column_name === 'thumb') {  
        echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb' );  
    }  
}
```

The custom column "thumb" shows properly but the category is no longer displayed. Please see image.

[image]

What is causing this? The categories show if I remove the custom columns.

Comment: What do you expect in that "Categories" column? By default, categories (the core "Categories" taxonomy) is not supported by custom post types. Does your custom post type support the core "Categories" taxonomy or do you want some other custom taxonomy in the "Categories" column? Please, explain.

Comment: @cybmeta I guess the OP is trying to manipulate the core "Posts". Look at the filters he is using.

Comment: @cybmeta `category`, not `categories`. `categories` can be a valid custom taxonomy

Comment: @Abhik `post`, not `posts`. `posts` can be a valid custom post type

Comment: @PieterGoosen the OP said: "I added a custom column to a custom post type", I don't he/she wants to manipulate the core "posts" type, or maybe yes.....who knows.

Comment: By the way @PieterGoosen, [`manage_posts_columns` filter applies to all post types except pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns). Same for [`manage_posts_custom_column` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)

Comment: can you edit your question and post your custom post type creation code as well, For default post it works fine. Can you  edit your question and add it. I can help you.

Comment: I mixed the comments from Pieter and the comments from Abhik, sorry. Pieter, I talked about core `category` taxonomy because `'categories' => 'Categories'` in the columns array is used for `category` taxonomy, at least in the standard post type. So, I think the problem can be related with this. I think the CPT supports a custom taxonomy labeled with "Categories" and the OP has confused it with the core `category` taxonomy. But it is just that, I thought, until the OP comes to clarify the problem I can not be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I tested this code and its working fine and steps here.

1. I am just creating a dummy `custom_post_type` here `book`  with the following code.

   ```
    function kv_custom_post_books() {
      $args = array(
       'public' => true,
       'label'  => 'Books',
       'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') , 
       'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
     );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'kv_custom_post_books' );
   ```

Here i am not sure, you used this line. `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')` . This one gets you the default categoires to  your custom post type.

2. Now we will rewrite your action hook here. and we use the same functions no change in it.

   ```
   add_filter('manage_edit-book_columns', 'custom_columns', 10);  
   add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns_thumb', 10, 2);  

   function custom_columns($columns) {         
      $columns = array(
         'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
         'title' => 'Title',
         'categories' => 'Categories', // not showing
         'thumb' => __('Thumb'),
         'date' => __( 'Date' )
      );
     return $columns;
   }  

   function custom_columns_thumb($column_name, $id){  
     if($column_name === 'thumb') {  
         echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb' );  
     }  
   }
   ```

**Note :** I just edited only one line in your code. `add_filter('manage_edit-book_columns', 'custom_columns', 10);`. We have to specify your custom post type in your  action hook. This is the ultimate thing here . `manage_edit-book_columns` Instead of default one we have to specify the custom post type name here.

Here I attached a screenshot  for you,

[image]

Comment: According with codex, [`manage_edit-${post_type}_columns` filter was supplanted by `manage_${post_type}_posts_columns` since WP 3.1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns), almost 5 years ago (although `manage_edit-${post_type}_columns` still works and it is not marked as deprecated). Also, `manage_posts_columns` filter, used by the OP, is absolutely valid and applies to all posts types except pages. I think the used filter is not the problem.

Comment: I am not answering by just reading codec.  I tested it completely.  Than I posted my code.  Also I attached a screenshot for reference. There @Abhik edited his answer as well.

Comment: Sorry @Kvvaradha, it seems that you didn't understand my comment. I didn't say that your code doesn't work. Please, read my comment again.

Comment: I understand it. You are saying  that there is an action supplanted for the action hook which I used. Your suggestion is right.  But I preferred my desired one. That's it.

Comment: Yes, I said that and also that it is not the problem because changing one filter for the another makes no difference for the problem described in the question. Sorry if I was not good enough with the explanation. And this is the same discussion we had with Abhik, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `Thumb` Column instead of re-defining the whole columns.

```
function custom_columns($columns) {  
    return array_merge( $columns, 
        array( 'thumb' => __('Thumb', 'mytextdomain' ),
        ) );
}
```

Also, make sure if you accidentally `unset` the Categories column when you removed the `Tags`, `Author` and `Comments` columns.

**EDIT**
After seeing the little search button label at the top right corner of the second screenshot, I can see that you are indeed using a Custom Post Type. In that case, if you want associate the default "Categories" to your CPT, use this piece of code with the current array of arguments that registers your CPT:

`'taxonomies' => array('category');`

Also, change your filters to `manage_post_type_posts_columns` and `manage_post_type_posts_columns`. Where `post_type` is your CPT.

Thanks to cybmeta and PieterGoosen for the comments.

Comment: I guess you edited your answer after seeing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new columns without breaking the bank, I find storing the old values first helps to make sure you keep what is there and only add what you need. If you want to see less then adjust with screen options.

```
$post_type = 'posts';
add_filter("manage_${post_type}_posts_columns", 'posts_set_custom_columns', 10);
add_action("manage_${post_type}_posts_custom_column", 'posts_render_custom_columns', 10, 2);

function posts_set_custom_columns ($columns) {

    // save existing settings for columns

    $before = array(
        'cb' => $columns ['cb'],
        'title' => $columns ['title'],
        'categories' => $columns ['categories'],
    );

    // remove all the items before our new columns

    foreach ($before as $inx => $label) {
        unset($columns[$inx]);
    }

    // push our new columns to the front

    $columns = array_merge(
        array(
            'thumb' => __('Thumb'),
    ), $columns);

    // put the first items back in the front

    $columns = array_merge($before, $columns);

    return $columns;
}

function posts_render_custom_columns ($column_name, $id) {
    if($column_name === 'thumb') {

        $size = 'thumbnail';

        // display the image or a mark to let us know it's missing
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $id ))
            the_post_thumbnail( $size );
         else
             echo "-";
    }
}
```

- [manage_$post_type_posts_columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns)
- [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)

Comment: `manage_{$post_type}_columns` should be `"manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` and `manage_{$post_type}_custom_column` should be `manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`.

Comment: So many? This answer has only 1 downvote (not mine by the way)

Answer (score 0):

**slider** to change your post name and 
**slider_category** to change  **your taxonomy category name**

```
    <?php
/** Manage column Function */
add_filter("manage_edit-slider_columns", "slider_edit_columns");
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column", "slider_custom_columns");

function slider_edit_columns($columns) {
    $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Title",
        "slider_category" => "Categories",  
        "date" => "Date",
    );
    return $columns;
}

function slider_custom_columns($column) {
    global $post;
    switch ($column) {
       case 'thumb':
             echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb' );  
        break;
        case "slider_category":  
            echo $cat = strip_tags(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'slider_category', '', ', ',''));  
        break;  
    default:
      break;
    }
}
```