# Show only first image of multiple image field

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field called "attachment" and in this field there is more than 1 image (average 10-15 images). When I setup this custom field in a custom column post (for now I used this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/),), I see every image for every custom post (so this is a very slow site).

How can I show only the first image of the images in the custom field?

I have read a similar question in the [WordPress.org forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/feature-request-1st-attachment-only/), but no solution was posted.

This is for a custom post type called "property".

In this image you can see the structure of the field and content:

[image]

Comment: i don't tried a code, the custom field is "attachment"

Answer (score 0):

Below are four examples of getting a list of items, returning the first and showing a single image from the first id.

- [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) assumes your data is in a string separated by commas.
- [get_attached_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media_) pulls all the attached items in a post then renders the first from that list
- [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) assumes the data lives in an array -- for testing it'll create an array of ids
- [get_post_custom_values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) seems to pull in the post meta unserialized so you'll need to run [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize);

---

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
// get your custom field data (this looks like your meta_value)

$meta_value = "378,377,376,375,374,373"; 

// convert csv to array

$ids = explode ( ',', $meta_value );

// pull the first item out as the variable $id

list($id) = $ids;

// show the image

echo wp_get_attachment_image ( $id, 'medium' );
```

---

[get_attached_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media_)

```
// assume you have these vals
$post = get_post();
$post_id = $post->ID;

// get the attachments
$attachments = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);
if(count($attachments) > 0) {
    $first_attachment = array_shift($attachments);
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID);
}
```

---

[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

```
$post = get_post();
$post_id = $post->ID;
$key = 'attachment';

$generate_if_not_found = false; // for testing
if($generate_if_not_found && empty(get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true))) {
    // write the values if we don't have them
    update_post_meta($post_id, $key, array(386, 393, 234, 23, 23, 234));
}

$ids = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
if( ! empty($ids) && count($ids) > 0) {
    $first_id = array_shift($ids);
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_id);
}
```

---

[get_post_custom_values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values)

```
$post = get_post();
$post_id = $post->ID;
$key = 'attachment';

if(is_array($value = get_post_custom_values($key, $post_id))) {
    if(count($value) > 0) {
        if(is_array($ids = maybe_unserialize($value[ 0 ]))) {
            if(count($ids) > 0) {
                $id = array_shift($ids);
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Custom Column](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211502/84219)

```
function posts_render_custom_columns($column_name, $post_id) {
    if($column_name === 'attachment') {

        $size = 'thumbnail';

        $attachments = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);
        if(count($attachments) > 0) {
            $first_attachment = array_shift($attachments);
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID, $size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but what is  "$ids_str" , in my site is present more thousand of photo, with your code every image i want add i'ts request a change in this script ?

Comment: i want show a column called "image gallery" in the list of custom post "property",  in this column i want show only the first image of post_attachments , this is my goal, now i understand your code but i want a dynamic value in $ids_str

Comment: i have updated the first question , you can show the code of file that generate the frontend output, i think the correct fncyion is this https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column